# how to select the newly added rows in a table efficiently?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, performance, relational-database

I need to periodically update a local cache with new additions to some DB table. The table rows contain an auto-increment *sequential number* (SN) field. The cache keeps this number too, so basically I just need to fetch all rows with SN larger than the highest I already have.

```
SELECT * FROM table where SN > <max_cached_SN>
```

However, **the majority of the attempts will bring no data** (I just need to make sure that I have an absolutely up-to-date local copy). So I wander if this will be more efficient:

```
count = SELECT count(*) from table;
if (count > <cache_size>)
  // fetch new rows as above
```

I suppose that selecting by an indexed numeric field is quite efficient, so I wander whether using `count` has benefit. On the other hand, this test/update will be done quite frequently and by many clients, so there is a motivation to optimize it.

Comment: do you query the cache by SN only, or by other fields as well?

Comment: @Ronnis: no, I search it by the real data. The SN is only for sync

Comment: ok. Otherwise you could have delayed the refresh until your cache gets a request for "ID > max_cached_id".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*)` may involve a scan (even a full scan), while `SELECT ... WHERE SN > constant` can effectively use an index by SN, and looking at very few index nodes may suffice. Don't count items if you don't need the exact total, it's expensive.

Comment: I actually expected (hoped) that `select count(*)` would just read some table metadata that probably resides in memory, so it should be quite efficient?

Comment: @davka: it very much depends on the table size. Generally you need to `explain plan` and be ready for sometimes unpleasant surprises.

Comment: `select count(*)` will only be fetching "metadata" if you are  using a non-transactional storage engine. But as soon as transactions are involved, the DBMS must read go to the table to find out if a certain row is currently visible for your select or not.

Answer (score 3):

> this **test**/update will be done quite frequently and by many clients

this could lead to unexpected race competition for cache generation

I would suggest

- upon new addition to your table add the newest id into a queue table
- using like crontab to trigger the cache generation by checking queue table
- upon new cache generated, delete the id from queue table

as you stress **majority of the attempts will bring no data**, the above will only trigger where there is new addition

and the queue table concept, even can expand for update and delete

Comment: thanks. We considered (and probably will be, eventually) using publish/subscriber notification mechanism to trigger updates. The thing is that there are several clients each maintaining such local cache, so it is not possible to have a central queue table. It gives me an idea thought to send update notifications not on each update (trigger) but on scheduled intervals

Answer (score 2):

I believe that

```
SELECT * FROM table where SN > <max_cached_SN>
```

will be faster, because select count(*) may call table scan. Just for clarification, do you never delete rows from this table?

Comment: the opposite ... `select *` unlikely to make use on index, and cause table scan instead

Comment: no (or yes?), I never delete rows; also, I expected that `select count(*)` just fetches the table size for some metadata, hopefully even in memory

Comment: @ajreal: I expect that `select * ... where key>value` should use the index and be quite efficient, isn't it so?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `SELECT COUNT(*)`

There is two solution.

1. You can use a `temp table` that has `one field` that contain `last count of your table`, and create new `Trigger` after insert on your table and inc temp table field in Trigger.
2. You can use a `temp table` that has one field that contain `last SN` of your table is cached and create new Trigger after insert on your table and update temp table field in Trigger.

Comment: thanks. We considered #2 (not doing it initially, though), but this would help me finding out the `max cached SN`. It will not help with checking if there where new additions to the main table - it still would be `... where SN > max_cached_SN`, and that's my concern here.

Comment: if you don't want to use any where command, you can use an another table ('table2') that schema is like your main table('table1'). all of your new rows added to table2 and you only check table2 rows and process that's and then move its from table2 to table1.

Answer (score -1):

not much to this really

```
drop table if exists foo;
create table foo
(
foo_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key
)
engine=innodb;

insert into foo values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null);

select * from foo order by foo_id desc limit 10;

insert into foo values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null);

select * from foo order by foo_id desc limit 10;
```

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand your solution. Why `limit 10`? I need all new entries since the last update. Have you read my question?

Comment: ah must have mis-read your question - or you changed it. "how to select the newly added rows in a table efficiently?"